# Exit Program with Switch Default?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, user-defined-functions

I am trying to code the program so it will exit whenever a number is entered OTHER than 1 or 2. I'm able to get it to display an "exit message", but the program restarts rather than exiting. I believe it may be because there is no "return 0" in the switch default, but I kept getting a return error for void calcit when I included it. I feel like it's something simple that I am missing.

Comment: " but the program restarts" That's not the case. Take a look here `do { ... }
    while (true);`. You never get out of this loop, which means `if(resp != '1' || resp != '2')` is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the program never ending is because you have the loop `do {blah blah....} while (true)` which never ends.  To achieve what you want you need a different condition:

```
do { blah blah blah ...} while (resp == '1' || resp == '2');
```

Answer (score -1):

To exit form your program you should use exit functions in place of return 0 that will terminate your loop as well
Break would not help you out because you are in switch block as well as the do while loop
So, try exit (0); to terminate you also have to include the header file that

is`#include<cstdlib. h>`

Comment: `std::exit` is in `<cstdlib>`, not `process.h` (which is not a standard header at all). It also terminates the program without unwinding the stack, leaking all resources.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but I didn't got that leaking all resources thing you said

Comment: C++ uses RAII to manage resources, and it's the role of destructors to free said resources. Since `std::exit` does not call the destructors of automatic variables, the resources are never freed.

Comment: Is there a way to call a destructor before that exit function

Comment: Either direct the program flow to return to `main` and finish normally, or (but I do not recommend it) `throw` an exception and catch it in `main`.

Comment: What's the problem in exception handling

Comment: Well, exceptions are not meant to be used as flow control. They're only for exceptional conditions -- hence the name.